# On local New User Registered email not sending in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email-validation

I am new to wordpress. I am working on Localhost with woo-commerce. When a new user is registered, email verification link is not sending to the user and also for admin.
Should i need SMTP for this or any other settings to fix.

Comment: Any error you getting?

Comment: No, it is not showing any error.

Comment: Try to add SMTP plugin and check test mail is working or not https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Comment: You need to add SMTP details in this plugin. I send a plugin link is the best plugin ever try this

Comment: I tried SMTP plugin but test mail is not working,

Comment: I just checked forgot password from wordpress for admin also can't send email. I think issue is in my local server, By the way i am using flywheel.

Answer (score 0):

In localhost, an email will not be sent due to lack of access to the server

This problem will be solved by transferring the site to a server and making the site online

If you forgot your password, you can change it through the database

```
phpmyadmin
your database > wp_users
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for WordPress to send emails on localhost.

You can use SMTP or find out what is preventing emails from being sent.

For SMTP, I recommend using the plugin [WP Mail SMTP By WP Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/). I should add that I don't particularly like this plugin, but it works!!

If you don't want to use the plugin, you can also google 'how to use SMTP in WordPress without a plugin.'

To find out what might be causing the issue, you can use the plugin [Check & Log Email](https://wordpress.org/plugins/check-email/). I highly recommend this plugin! It helped me find out the cause of my problem in minutes.

If the problem is that WordPress is trying to send emails from "WordPress@localhost" (I suspect it is), then you can just change the 'from address' and you'll be on your way.

WordPress has a filter for changing the 'from address' used by wp_mail. So you can easily do something like so:

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'get_admin_email');

if(!function_exists('get_admin_email')) {
    function get_admin_email($email) {
        $wp_from = get_option('admin_email');
        return $wp_from;
    }
}
```

The code above tells WordPress to use the admin email address as the 'from address'.

Further reading:

[WordPress Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_from/)

[My Blog](https://mwale.me/error-email-could-not-be-sent-site-may-not-be-correctly-configured-wordpress-not-sending-emails-on-localhost-xampp/)

HTH,
Mwale